# Setting custom number format pattern as fr-CA without specifying culture

Tags: c#, .net

I am struggling to apply the correct number format pattern to obtain the following:
1 000 000,00 using something like this"### ###,000". I am aware that by setting the culture in the code, we can specify a region such as fr-CA to obtain the desired formatting without setting a custom pattern. Although this works really well, I am looking for an alternative solution to avoid specifying culture. For some reason, the decimals delimiter is always recognized as being the "." period and I cannot set a comma instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18377793/1275774) with [`string.Format`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278271/1275774).

```
decimal myDecimal = 12345.67m;

NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," };

string formattedNumber = string.Format(nfi, "{0:### ### ###.###}", myDecimal);

Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber); // Prints "12 345,67"
```

[Here's a fiddle for you](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ddsCqC).